# How to determine the max partition size?

Tags: filesystems, ext3

How to determine what parameters decides that max partition size of an OS would be like 16TB in ext3 or any of the other filesystem?

Comment: Wikipedia has information about maximum file system sizes and implementation limits. For example: [ext3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3), [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be different for each type of filesystem.  For ext3 and ext4, you can determine the max partition size by:

- Getting the block size with `tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 'Block size:'`
- Checking for a 64bit flag on the filesystem: `tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 64bit`
- If there is one, multiplying the blocksize by 2<sup>64</sup>.  Otherwise multiplying it by 2<sup>32</sup>.
- Dividing that number by 1024<sup>4</sup> to get terabytes.